# How to migrate from Vue 2 to Vue 3 where application is using axios interceptors and Vuex store to provide globally defined notification dialog box

Tags: vue.js, pinia

We have a Vue2 application that is already working with this setup (Vue2 and Vuetify).

The goal and how it is achieved in Vue2:

(Some code are removed for brevity)
in main.js, router configuration

```
    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            {
                path: "",
                component: menu,
                props: true,
                children: [...]
```

in menu.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app style="background-color:#f8f8f8;">
    <router-view></router-view>
    <v-dialog v-model="$store.state.notification.show" width="500px">
            ...
    </v-dialog>
```

in main.js again

```
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    vuetify,
    render: display => display(application),
    data: function() {
        return {
            loader: { count: 0, stroke: 7, diameter: 50, value: false },
        };
    },
    created: function() {
        axios.interceptors.response.use(
            response => {
                if (response.data && response.data.type === "MESSAGE") {
                    store.commit("showNotification", { title: "Notification", content: response.data });
                }
                return response;
            },
            error => {
                let notification = { title: "Unknown error", content: "" };
                if (error.response) {
                    notification.content = error.response.data;
                }
                store.commit("showNotification", notification);
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
    },
    methods: {
    }
```

With this setup, if axios receives an error (non 200 http code) from the backend, it will execute Vuex store.commit("showNotification", notification). That in turn will make the v-dialog pop up appear that is defined in menu.vue, which if you look at the router configuration, is "wrapping" other components (the child component is shown in menu.vue's ), therefore each child component does not need to define the error v-dialog.
Note that in Vue2, in the "new Vue() call", the variable "store" is supplied, where it can be used inside the axios interceptor code block inside the created lifecyle hook.

How to do this in Vue3? Either by this same method or some other method that achieves the same goal?

What I've tried in Vue3

in main.js

```
const instance = createApp(application)
registerPlugins(instance)
instance.mount('#application')
```

in plugin folder

```
import vuetify from './vuetify'
import pinia from '../store'
import router from '../router'

export function registerPlugins (instance) {
    instance
        .use(vuetify)
        .use(router)
        .use(pinia)
}
```

in application.vue (formerly App.vue)

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data: function() {};
    },
    created: function() {
        axios.interceptors.response.use(
            error => {
                let notification = { title: "Unknown error", content: "" };
                if (error.response) {
                    notification.content = error.response.data;
                }
                store.commit("showNotification", notification); <-???
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
    }
```

This is not working because in main.js it does a createApp(application), which I assume will read application.vue and in its created hook, it has store.commit(), where it has no way of knowing what is this variable "store", since pinia is defined after createApp (in registerPlugins).

Comment: Use pinia useStore functions instead of $store